# For two unit speed curves $\gamma_{1,2}$ on $[0,l]$ where $0\leq k_2\leq k_1<\pi/l$, show $d(\gamma_1(0),\gamma_1(l))\leq d(\gamma_2(0),\gamma_2(l))$.

Tags: differential-geometry

For two unit speed curves $\gamma_{1,2}$ on $[0,l]$ where $0\leq k_2\leq k_1<\pi/l$, show $d(\gamma_1(0),\gamma_1(l))\leq d(\gamma_2(0),\gamma_2(l))$. It is important to note here that $d(\gamma_1(0),\gamma_1(l))$ does not refer to the arc length which is simply $l$ because they are unit speed. It is just the distance between the end points.

Here $\gamma_1$ is a planar curve and $\gamma_2$ a general unit speed curve in $\Bbb R^3$. $k_1$ and $k_2$ indicate the curvature of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ respectively. Now I have shown using the indicatrix of both curves that the angle between $\gamma'_1(0)$ and $\gamma_1'(l)$ is larger than or equal to the angle between $\gamma_2'(0)$ and $\gamma_2'(l)$. Then there is a hint given, namely that we may assume there exists a $s_0\in[0,l]$ such that 
$$\gamma_1'(s_0) = \frac{\gamma_1(l)-\gamma_1(0)}{|\gamma_1(l)-\gamma_1(0)|}.$$
Now the result makes intuitive sense. The curve that bends more in one direction will not have as long a distance from its endpoint to where it started. I do not really know how to continue this in a mathematically sound way though. How can help? Thanks!